# Authentication using Web Services in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-services

How to authenticate SharePoint online List service using web services. I have tried many solutions nothing was working.

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/40e97e/sharepoint-2010-web-services/

Comment: what have you tried so far? which kind of solution your are trying to connect via? Provide in detail information to understand the root cause